# How to conduct smtp with ssl inside a prompt?

Tags: ssl, smtp

If without ssl,I can simply:

```
telnet mx 25
EHLO xxxx
...
```

But when it's encrypted with ssl,is it still possible to type these commands step by step?

Answer (score 2):

yes, if server is using STARTTLS:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect host:25
```

if using SSL directly:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect host:465
```

from http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html:

> s_client - This implements a generic SSL/TLS client which can establish a
>   transparent connection to a remote
>   server speaking SSL/TLS. It's intended
>   for testing purposes only and provides
>   only rudimentary interface
>   functionality but internally uses
>   mostly all functionality of the
>   OpenSSL ssl library.

Comment: Can you be more specific about those switches?

Comment: yeah, you can replace host with the server's hostname. the full description is here: http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html